# Using GPG keys on multiple devices?

Tags: encryption, gpg

Say I encrypt a file using my private GPG key on my desktop. I then transfer the file to my laptop, and intend to decrypt it. What do I do? I heard something about "exporting a public key", what does this mean? Do I use the private key on my laptop as well? If I do, how do I put the private key from my desktop onto my laptop? I am just transferring encrypted files between my own personal machines, I am not giving them to anyone else, so do I still need the public key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encryption** is done with the **public key**.
**Decryption** with the **private key**.

Keys can bei exported to files and imported on another machine.
It's possible to upload the public key to a keyserver.

listing keys (find your id after "/")

```
gpg --list-keys
```

export private key (replace 12345ABCD with your id)

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor 1234ABCD > secret.asc
```

export public key (replace username@email with your email)

```
gpg --output public.pgp --armor --export username@email
```

import private key

```
gpg --import secret.asc
```